# Express in Nodejs Permission denied when entering DEBUG=app ./bin/www

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, express

I changed the name of 'my-application' to just 'app' but now when i enter the DEBUG command i get an error in the terminal:

i entered DEBUG=app ./bin/www 
by default it was 'my-application', when it is created by express. so i changed the name to 'app' and it gives the error below.

-bash ./bin/www Permission denied

any ideas how to fix this?, i even tried to run it as root.

Comment: You're trying to execute a file called `./bin/www` (not sure why, as you say it's called "app"), and it probably doesn't have [executable permissions](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0090.php).

Comment: i asked Express.js to make a project name exp2014 and then i installed all the dependencies. I was able to run the application at first by typing DEBUG=my-application ./bin/www

Comment: So you're using `express@3.x` (the CLI tool was removed in v4.x)? That still doesn't provide me with a `./bin/www` script (or a `./bin` directory to begin with).

Comment: the path is like this projectname/bin/www

Comment: Can you post the contents of `./bin/www`?

Comment: I just removed the whole folder and will do it again, I am learning node.js and moving from PHP to Node.js. I watched a tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqMIyTH9wSg&feature=iv&src_vid=ndKRjmA6WNA&annotation_id=annotation_2934154685      ; in the video the uploader makes a sample project and then opens a www file, which lies in the bin folder. He then changes the name my-application to app at exactly 4:58. I tried to do the same but i get a permission error.

Comment: Okay, so you're using `express-generator`. You should make sure that you're using the latest version, which (by default) create "app.js" instead of "my-application.js" as the app entry point.

Comment: Oh thank you!, then i suppose i really am using an older version.

Comment: @robertklep The latest version still defines the entry point as `./bin/www`. `app.js` is a module and won't run on it's own. [Source](https://github.com/expressjs/generator/blob/master/templates/js/app.js)

Comment: @BenFortune I wouldn't call `./bin/www` the app entry point, but potato-potato :-) <s>The initial problem was that the JS file that is now called `app.js` was previously named after the project name (`my-application.js`), and renaming it was causing problems</s> No never mind, the *DEBUG* string was changed...

Answer (score 4):

You can set the proper permissions on the file to ensure you no longer get that error:

```
sudo chmod 755 ./bin/www
```

Comment: it creates bin folder in application root when running app which needed sudo permissions.